# azure enterprise app user in group not able to login

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm creating an app with angular and ADALService to connect to Azure AD, however after assigning group to the app in azure portal, the user inside the group is not able to login.

Currently the `user/group` to this app have role `Default Access`

Any idea what goes wrong? or what other things I need to set?

Thanks.

Comment: Any error message? Can you post more details about your scenario?

Comment: Hi, my NT team managed to resolve it, it just lacks some permission..